# Where does apache store initialization state for mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: apache-2.2

I run `apache2` on Ubuntu as a caching load-balancing reverse proxy in front of a group of application servers. I have noticed that the balancer maintains some state for some of the attributes visible in `/balancer-manager` such as whether an IP is enabled/disabled, load factor, etc.

My site has periods of high (and low) usage, and recently as I added a new server to the working group I noticed that the load balancer picked up the new server but had it set to `Disabled`. I'm curious where that data is stored, and/or how it is initialized.

Balancer config (names changed to protect the innocent:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
<Proxy balancer://main>
    BalancerMember https://10.10.1.1
    BalancerMember https://10.10.1.2
    BalancerMember https://10.10.1.3
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass /  balancer://main/
ProxyPassReverse /  balancer://main/
```

UPDATE: code spelunking shows the balancer status stored in-memory only in `v2.2.0` as the struct `ap_scoreboard` and reinitialized on startup. There's no way the thing I think I'm seeing is happening. Kudos to @ShaneMadden for the insights into `v2.4`.

Comment: Do you mean that changes that are made via the balancer manager (and not in the config files) are persisting across restarts of the apache service?

Comment: So it would seem. It is unclear what Enabled state will be when I add a server IP into the rotation, if that server was once a part of the balancer group.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Persistence of managed balancer-manager state is a new feature in Apache 2.4.

Comment: @EJP So it is, I had missed that one!  The changes doc says "can be persistent", but I'm not seeing any directive that governs whether persistence is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature seems to be a bit of a mess.. the idea seems to be to use `mod_slotmem_shm` to persist balancer configs, which has an option to make its storage persistent.

To that end, the `.shm` files in your `logs` directory (location does not seem to be configurable) are where the configurations are stored, which seems to only happen on 2.4.2 and later.  The file will be named `slotmem-shm-<identifier>_balancername.shm` for a balancer defined as `<Proxy balancer://balancername>`, for example.

However, in my testing the `.shm` file isn't created at all in 2.4.1, and doesn't persist through a service restart in 2.4.2 and 2.4.3.  Can you clarify what conditions you have that are causing persistence - what modules are in use, what config, etc?  Are the `.shm` files staying put when the service is stopped?

It looks like a change was [committed today](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-cvs/201209.mbox/%3C20120917171945.421752388900@eris.apache.org%3E) to do some logging relating to persistence.  I tried to compile trunk to test out whether that would help clarify what's going on, and couldn't compile due to errors related to slotmem (go figure).

Comment: Running v2.2.20 (Ubuntu), so not using the new features in 2.4, and not loading the slotmem module. The issue seems to persist beyond just reboots; the LB/RP runs in Amazon EC2 and the "remembered state" exists in my stored AMI. It may be time for me to do some code spelunking, as I am curious where the init values come from if you don't provide them in `proxy_balancer.conf`.

Comment: @khoxsey Hmm.. there shouldn't be any state storage, then - I wonder if something else strange is at work.  What's the config for your balancer look like?

Comment: Agreed about the state storage, I was surprised the first time I noticed it, and more curious each time it happens. Posted the config for review.